# Angular - Using a component selector as an attribute makes tslint get angry

Tags: angular, tslint

I'm trying to create a component with an attribute as a selector, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[my-attribute-selector]',
    template: ``
})
export class MyComponent { 
   // Some cool stuff
}
```

However, tslint is complaining about that, with the following message:

```
[tslint] The selector of the component "MyComponent" should be used as element
```

I know I could just disable that tslint rule, but I'd like to know if there's a reasonable reason why I shouldn't use an attribute as the component's selector before doing so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To allow linting for *both* element and attribute selectors, in `tslint.config` pass in an array `["element", "attribute"]` instead of `"element"` or just `"attribute"`:

```
"component-selector": [
        true,
        ["element", "attribute"],
        "app",
        "kebab-case"
    ]
```

As per reasons of taking the attribute approach, I will quote from [this issue on codelyzer](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/307). Basically it's advisable when intending to just wrap low-level native input functionality like `button` or `input` without having to put a `<my-custom-input>` around them.

> After listening to [Angular Material team's talk in ng-conf about
>   component API designs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BikjL858OQ) there is a case for using attribute selectors as
>   components to allow components to be able to use the DOM API without
>   needing to reflect 20+ bindings from the custom element style
>   components to the inner DOM API it wraps.

Answer (score 13):

Your `tslint.config` file will be having this rule

```
"component-selector": [
  "element",
  "app",
  "kebab-case"
],
```

Please modify that to allow `attribute` selector as below

```
"component-selector": [
  "attribute", 
  "myPrefix", 
  "camelCase"
]
```

Comment: Hi @Aravind! Thanks for answering! As I said in my question, I know I could change/disable the rule in the tslint config file. However, what I was asking is if there is a reason why I shouldn't use an attribute as the component's selector.

Comment: Components are should be having element selectors and directives should be having attribute selectors

Comment: yes I know but since Directives (as far as I know) can't have a template, I wanted to use an attribute as a selector so I can avoid extra tags like `<my-selector><div>foo</div></my-selector>`, which would break my css. That's why I wanted to know why using an attribute as the component's selector is not a "good practice" according to tslint.  Anyway, I think I'm gonna just disable the rule for that line with `/* tslint:disable-next-line */` for now (kinda dirty tho...).